# Is there a specific way to cancel tasks in django celery

Tags: python, django, celery

my issue is I have a function that executes every 3 days by means of celery's apply_async. I set a pending order to cancelled if it doesnt get approved in 2 days. The problem is, if the admin reconsiders it and changes the status back to pending, the timer should restart, the expiration doesnt terminate. I'm not sure if celery's .revoke() will specifically cancel just one .expire() call. I don't want them all to stop just one specific. Can anyone help?

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task(name="expire")

def expire(order_id):
    print(order_id)
    print("this works")
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
        print(order)
    except:
        print(f"Failed retrieving order object of id {order_id}")
        return

    if order.status != "P":
        return

    # Place products back to inventory
    line_items = order.orderlineitems_set.all()

    for line_item in line_items:
        product = line_item.product
        quantity = line_item.quantity

        product.quantity += quantity
        product.save()

    # Cancel order
    order.status = "C"
    print(order.status)
    order.save()
```

**views.py**

```
class PurchaseView(View):
    @staticmethod
    @login_required
    @customer_required
    def get(request):
        cart = Cart(request=request)

        if not cart.is_approved:
            print("Cart is not approved")
            return redirect("/checkout/cart/")

        customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        order = cart.convert_to_order(customer=customer)
        cart.reset_cart()
        print(order.status)
        expire.apply_async(args=(order.id,), eta=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3))

        context = make_context(request)
        context["total_price"] = order.total_price

        return render(request, 'purchase.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a bind=True and using self to get the task id

```
@app.task(bind=True, name="expire")
def expire(self,order_id):
    print(f"the task queue id is {self.request.id}")
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
        print(f"the order status is {order.status}")
    except:
        print(f"Failed retrieving order object of id {order_id}")
        return


    if order.status == "C":
        print(f"this process terminated, order status:{order.status}")
        app.control.revoke(self.request.id, terminate = True)
```